# How to add child layout in linear layout which will be equally spaced

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout which has horizontal orientation.
What i want to do is, i want to add images at runtime and those images should be equally spaced in the linear layout. For better understanding  here is the desired output.

[image]

But i am getting both images at the right end one after another.

Here is the code snippets.

> 1) Parent layout (test.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/test"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
></LinearLayout>`
```

> 2)Child Layout (test_image.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/testTab"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/testImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

> Here is the Activity where i am adding children in parent layout`

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

private  LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStste)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStste);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) Test.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.test);

    LinearLayout tab = provideTab(R.drawable.rottentomatoes);
    LinearLayout tab1 = provideTab(R.drawable.rottentomatoes);

    layout.addView(tab);
    layout.addView(tab1);

}

public LinearLayout provideTab(int id)
{

    LinearLayout cardView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_image,null);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.testImage);
    imageView.setImageResource(id);

    return cardView;
}}
```

What am i missing here.
(When i add child layout in parent layout using include tag images are getting equally spaced).
Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your full parentLayout so ?

Comment: my bad @IbrahimAli i have updated the parent layout code . have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line on your `provideTab` method to

```
LinearLayout cardView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_image, layout, false);
```

where `layout` is the parent LinearLayout (returned from `(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.test)`).

That second param will provide a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)).

Comment: That's very strange. I copied all of your code, replicated your error, then that change fixed the problem.

Comment: my bad i had included the layout in xml also which i forgot to remove during testing . Your code works as charm thanks  alot .

Answer (score 1):

Your child views need to know where they are attaching to get the weights right. That is why including works but your code doesn't. Try the following code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import junit.framework.Test;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);

        LinearLayout tab = provideTab(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        LinearLayout tab1 = provideTab(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

        layout.addView(tab);
        layout.addView(tab1);
    }

    public LinearLayout provideTab(int id) {

        // Let the inflater know what the parent ViewGroup is (layout) but don't attach (false)
        LinearLayout cardView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_image, layout, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.testImage);
        imageView.setImageResource(id);

        return cardView;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already tried it before asking this question . but i tried once again . seems not to work. thanks btw. I think the problem is with the width of the child layout.

Comment: my bad, i had included the child layout in xml also thats why it was taking some junk space. Your code works fine . thanks alot but there could be only one accepted answer. thank you for your time.